# Преобразование фото формата webp в png на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pillow, pil, конвертация

у меня есть фун-я

```
def convert(photo_name: str) -> str:
    """Convert .webp to .png
    :param
    :photo_name = saved photo name
    :return saved .png photo name"""

    new_png_name = f"{photo_name}.png"

    with Image.open(f'stickers/{photo_name}.webp').convert('RGB') as img:
        img.save(new_png_name, 'png')

    os.remove(f'stickers/{photo_name}.webp')
    return new_png_name
```

`os.remove()` выдает ошибку `os.remove(f'stickers/{photo_name}.webp') PermissionError: [WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом: 'stickers/file_14.webp'`

файл не закрыт, не понимаю почему, я так же пробовал вручную через `img.close()`

Comment: А если `.convert('RGB')` убрать из блока `with` попробовать? Не факт что поможет, но я бы попробовал.

Comment: пробовал, тоже самое(

Comment: А "вручную" файл удаляется? Ну можно ещё `time.sleep()` сделать на пару секунд перед удалением.

Comment: вручную после выброса ошибки да, ибо скрипт ложится, sleep() только что попробовал, тоже самое(

Comment: Даже долгий `sleep` не помогает? Ну странно вообще. Осталось ещё `gc.collect()` попробовать )

Comment: ну это жесть. грабер не помогает, я не понимаю почему оно не закрывается(

Comment: Может сделать `newimg = img.copy()`, потом `newimg.save()` и `newimg.close()`. Может `PIL` глючит, что у имиджа два файла и она не тот файл закрывает - только новый, а старый не закрывает.

Comment: к сожалению без изменений, так же говорит что занят другим процессом(

Comment: А вообще этот `webp` файл там изначально где-то лежит, или его этот скрипт ранее скачивает сам на диск? Может он его где-то раньше нормально не закрывает?

Comment: он скачивается из телеграм-бота, но не открывается нигде до этого

Comment: не думал что скачивание открывает файл. сделал .close() после скачивания, все заработало, спасибо большое, напишите это ответом к вопросу)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По результатам обсуждения в комментариях выяснилось, что проблемный файл скачивался чуть раньше этим же скриптом и после скачивания не закрывался. В результате файл можно было читать, но нельзя было удалить, пока скрипт не завершится. Закрытие файла после скачивания помогло решить проблему.